# cant add string to list of string c#

Tags: c#

I'm reading a local csv file which has data and I will eventually use to load into a database. My question is simple in nature but I can't seem to grasp the concept. Below is my code. Pretty simple stuff.

```
      static void loadTables() {
        int size = new int();
        string[] empid = new string[0];
       
        //string[] empid = new string();
        List<string[]> EmployeeName = new List<string[]>();
        List<string[]> EmployeeId = new List<string[]>();
        List<string[]> Group = new List<string[]>();
        List<string[]> Org = new List<string[]>();
        List<string[]> Fund = new List<string[]>();
        try {
            using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader("C:\\temp\\groupFundOrgReport.csv")) 
            {
             string line;
              string[] row;
              size = 0;
              while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
              {
                  row = line.Split(',');
                  /*resize the array up by 1*/
                  Array.Resize(ref empid,empid.Length+1);
                  /*I'm using size as a counter to add to the slot on the array.*/
                  empid[size] = row[0].Remove(0,1);
                  // here I receive error (the best overload match of system generic list?...etc) 
                  EmployeeName.Add(row[0]);
                  size++;
                  
              }

             }
           }
    
        catch(Exception e){

            Console.WriteLine(e);
        
        }
    
    
    
    
    }
```

I have a list of string but any attempts to add a string to it gets me an error. In other words if I try to do this **EmployeeName.Add(row[0].ToString);** I get an error. However if I comment the line out I can use an old fashion array. I really like to use a list but I can't seem to be able to pass the value that I want. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: i have also tried **EmployeeName.Add(row[0]);** with no luck

Comment: Isn't row[0] a single string - not a string[]?

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>.Add(string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: `empid` should be a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]`.  It's much easier to add an item to a List than an array, due to the differences in how those two types are designed.

Comment: yes row[0] is a single string that changes during the while statement. if i just do **row** it works but then thats not really what im looking for i like to get the first column into its own array.

Comment: `string.Split` is a poor way to parse a CSV file.  It's simpler to use a library, like http://www.filehelpers.com/

Comment: I'll note that the answers are answering your main problem.  I'm just pointing out other things that could use improvement. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess from your code that the employee name is the first field of the CSV file.

You have declared EmployeeName as a List of arrays of strings `List<string[]>`, not as a list of strings `List<string>`.

Row[0] is the first string in an array, so you are trying to add a string to a list that is expecting you to add an array of strings.

You should just declare EmployeeName as a `List<string>`, using a line like:

```
List<string> EmployeeName = new List<string>();
```

or

```
var EmployeeName = new List<string>();
```

Comment: i get it now. i was using list of arrays when what i was trying to use is list of strings. I feel like a real big idiot. Forgive my noobness. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the declaration of `EmployeeName`, it is a `List` of `string` arrays:

```
List<string[]> EmployeeName = new List<string[]>();
```

Change it to:

```
var EmployeeName = new List<string>();
```

Or, use the `List<string[]>` accordingly ...

Answer (score 2):

`EmployeeName` is a `List<string[]>` so you have to write:

```
EmployeeName.Add(row);
```

To remove empty entries while splitting a string use:

```
row=line.Split(New String() {","},
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

All of them are `List`'s of `String Array`'s

```
List<string[]> EmployeeName = new List<string[]>(); 
List<string[]> EmployeeId = new List<string[]>(); 
List<string[]> Group = new List<string[]>(); 
List<string[]> Org = new List<string[]>(); 
List<string[]> Fund = new List<string[]>();
```

Only variable you can add would be like

```
//Define array of strings
var strArr = new string[] {"abc", "xyz"};
```

then you can call

```
EmployeeName.Add(strArr);
```

although changing the `List` generic type to `string` type will solve your problem

```
List<string> EmployeeName = new List<string>(); 
List<string> EmployeeId = new List<string>(); 
List<string> Group = new List<string>(); 
List<string> Org = new List<string>(); 
List<string> Fund = new List<string>();

var str = "My String";

EmployeeName.Add(str);
```