# Another class property call from base class list

Tags: c#

I have a two class properdata and pprosecnddata both classes having property 
   I want to access product property from properdata class list object. How is it possible,below is my sample code

```
pupilc class ProperData
{
  public string code{get;set;}
  public List<ProSecndData>Secnd{get;set;}
}

public class ProSecndData
{
  public string product{get;set;}
}
```

I am trying to call property like that

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProperData.Secnd.Product = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem specifically, what error do you get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cant add string to list of string c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255152/cant-add-string-to-list-of-string-c-sharp)

Comment: I want to access product property like below form

Comment: ProperData.secnd.Product

Comment: There are a bunch of other small errors in your code. You're treating the property as `static` rather than creating an instance of the class, you've capitalized the `P` in `product`, and you're treating `Secnd` like a `ProSecndData` rather than a `List<ProSecndData>`

Answer (score 1):

you cannot directly access property of `Secnd` as it is a list

you need to iterate or select the index of the `List<Secnd>`

*you must initialize* `Secnd` *first* and `Secnd` should have items in the list

```
properData.Secnd = new List<ProSecndData>();
```

so it can be access via

```
foreach(var second in properData.Secnd)
{
    second.product = "hello";
}
//or
for(var i = 0; i < proderData.Secnd.Count(); i++)
{
    properData.Secnd[i].product = "hello";
}
//or

var index = //0-length of list;
properData.Secnd[index].product = "hello";
```

if you want to have items first then add first on your `Secnd` List

```
properData.Secnd = new List<ProSecndData>();
properData.Secnd.Add(new ProSecndData{ product = "hello"});
```

then you now can iterate the list by using methods above

Comment: @RajeshRajput you could mark it as answer if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access list as a single object, which is not possible.

you need to create single instance of your list class and then you can add string in that single instance.

```
 properData.Secnd = new List<ProSecndData>();
 ProSecndData proSecndData = new ProSecndData();
 proSecndData.product = "Hello";
 properData.Secnd.Add(proSecndData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually I know the answer already, you have not created a constructor to initialise your List.

I'm guessing you get a object null ref error?

Create the constructor to initialise your list and it should be fine.

But in future, please post the error message *(not the whole stack, just the actual error)* as well as **all** the code required to repeat the issue. Otherwise you run the risk of getting your question deleted

*(It should be deleted anyway because it could be considered a "what is a null ref err?" question).*

Also you are accessing an item in a list like the list is that item (should be more like: `ProperData.Secnd.elementAt(0).product`, please also note the capitalisation of 'product' in the model vs your code.